# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/MakeCalls/Static'

Tags: django, heroku

When doing 'git push heroku master' (from a Django app), the push gets rejected. I've included the traceback below. I can disable the collectstatic but then all the static files are missing from the webpage.

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` on my localserver it does not give any errors. I've spent the past two days on this, not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've included my `.settings` below for the staticfiles. I am using whitenoise which works perfectly fine on my localhost.

I think it has to do with a relative path that is not found. But that can't be it because there are no errors on my local server?

```
remote:      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
remote:            for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
remote:            for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
remote:            directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 299, in listdir
remote:            for entry in os.listdir(path):
remote:        OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/MakeCalls/Static'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Staticfiles:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ([
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'MakeCalls', 'Static'),    
])

STATIC_URL = '/Static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'MakeCalls', 'MakeCalls', 'Static')



MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Answer (score 10):

So I managed to fix this myself. The problem was that all my static files were organized in `root/Static` and served with `STATICFILES_DIRS`. However, for some reason, Heroku can't read this. So I put all static files in `root/app/static` and deleted the `STATICFILES_DIRS` in settings and it all worked!

Comment: So I commented out 'STATICFILES_DIRS' and it worked fine, is there any downside to this?

Comment: I suppose @Calco, since there won't be a central place to put static files that generic or non-app specific, e.g., bundling static files for a single-page app to a specific location, in this a static folder from where Django can find extra static files for use.