# Heroku error using collect static with Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, heroku, collectstatic

My app runs normally on my local and I can run

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

without error. But when pushing to Heroku at the end of the build process I get the following error:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 193, in handle
        collected = self.collect()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 115, in collect
        for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
        for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
        directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 399, in listdir
        for entry in os.listdir(path):
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_732715d9b29ba88f9eb56ca3d7e722de/MY_REAL_APP_NAME/static'
```

and so my build is rejected. I looked at [OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/MakeCalls/Static'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904685/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-tmp-makecalls-static) but when I remove my `STATICFILES_DIRS`, the app will deploy but all my static assets get a 404 error. I'm following the instructions on [Heroku exactly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets), but it doesn't seem to work. Relevant parts of my `settings.py` file is as follows:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

and my `wsgi.py` file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "fortuno.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

This all seems to work ok on my local, and when I run `heroku local web`. Any idea what might be causing the collect static error?

Comment: Did you create the "static" folder inside the Django project folder? If not, create one with an empty file. Look at the example repository in the Heroku documentation and the path for this empty [file](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/tree/master/gettingstarted/static)

Comment: Yup I have it. It's filled with my bootstrap files and images.

Comment: Can you show your project directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

STATIC FILE HANDLING IN DJANGO

in settings.py

```
import os
def root(folder):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..',folder)
```

create the static/media folder inside the project root

```
MEDIA_ROOT = root('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = root('staticstorage')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root('static'),
)
```

project root urls.py (project/project/urls.py)[django version 1.10 please reffer if you are not using this version]

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

make run `python manage.py collectstatic` in your local machine , if it's created staticstorage directory inside your project , it's done .... go ahead with deploy........